# How to conditionally fill a cell based on two conditions in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've done this in Base a bunch by manually entering the conditions that need to be met in order to set a new value of a new cell, but I really want to automate the process using dplyr.

This is the problem I currently have:
I have about 50 different places (only 3 in the code below), each with their own distance. I want to be able to set a segment value (Lets say 'a' 'b' or 'c') based on the values in the place and distance column. Note that there are repeating distance values.

`DF <- data.frame(place = c(rep('x',10), rep('y', 5), rep('z',5)), distance = c(0:9,5:9,5:9), segment = rep(NA,20))`

So, if something is at place 'x' and is above 0, it will have segment 'a'. If something is at place 'y' and is  above 5, it will have segment 'b'. Places 'z' above 5 will have segment 'c.'

In Base R, I would do this like this:
`DF$segment[DF$place == 'x' & DF$distance > 0] <- 'a'`

I just want to know if there was a dplyr way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
DF %>% 
  mutate(segment = case_when((place == "x" & distance > 0) ~ "a",
                             (place == "y" & distance > 5) ~ "b",
                             (place == "z" & distance > 5) ~ "c",
                             .default = NA))
```

If there is no match it will fill it up with NA. You can change that if you want.

Comment: Do note that `"NA"` is different from `NA`. You rarely want those quotes.

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you so much - you just saved me 50+ lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

The main `dplyr` verbs take the whole data frame as input, so we usually use `ifelse` (or `dplyr`'s own `if_else`) or `case_when` to handle updates that only occur on some rows.

```
DF |>
  mutate(segment = if_else(place == 'x' & distance > 0, 'a', segment))
```

For a single statement like this, it is quite verbose. However, you describe *"I want to be able to set a segment value (Lets say 'a' 'b' or 'c') based on the values in the place and distance column"*, and in this case doing all 3 in one statement would be pretty readable, say,

```
DF |>
  mutate(segment = case_when(
    place == 'x' & distance > 0 ~ 'a',
    distance == 0 ~ 'b',
    place %in% c('y', 'z') & distance > 5 ~ 'c',
    .default = segment 
  ))
```